# Why does `captures` not work in tmLanguage when the capture groups are too complex?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, tmlanguage

I'm wondering why `captures` isn't able to determine the capture groups when they get too complex.

I have created the following regex, and it only matches the first group.

```
(type)(((( |\t))|((\/\*(([^\*\/])+)?\*\/))|((\/\/(([^\n])+)?\n))))+(\&)?(\$|\_|[a-zA-Z])((\$|\_|[a-zA-Z0-9])+)?((((( |\t))|((\/\*(([^\*\/])+)?\*\/))|((\/\/(([^\n])+)?\n))))+)?(=)
```

When I change it to the following regex, the captures can be applied to the appropriate scopes in `captures`:

```
(type)(\s+)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\s+)(=)
```

Is this happening because it is a simplified regex, or because something is wrong with my capture groups?

**Breakdown of regex**

1: Find the type keyword

```
(type)
```

2: Whitespace or a comment

```
(((( |\t))|((\/\*(([^\*\/])+)?\*\/))|((\/\/(([^\n])+)?\n))))+
```

3: Variable name

```
(\&)?(\$|\_|[a-zA-Z])((\$|\_|[a-zA-Z0-9])+)?
```

4: Whitespace or a comment

```
(((( |\t))|((\/\*(([^\*\/])+)?\*\/))|((\/\/(([^\n])+)?\n))))+
```

5. Equal sign

```
(=)
```

**EDIT**

I noticed my regex is a bit messy, so here's a better one that also doesn't work:

```
/(type)((\/\*([^\*\/]+)?\*\/)|(\/\/([^\n]+)?\n)| |\t)+((\$|\_|[a-zA-Z])((\$|\_|[a-zA-Z0-9])+)?)((\/\*([^\*\/]+)?\*\/)|(\/\/([^\n]+)?\n)| |\t)+(=)/
```

Comment: your regex can be simplified a lot, and make all groups that you don't want to capture `(?:)` non capture groups, all is done on a line string, so `\n` will never happen

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you, I changed the comment parts to `(?:)` non capture groups. I also discovered that `([a-zA-Z$_][a-zA-Z$_0-9]*)` works, but `([a-zA-Z$_]([a-zA-Z$_0-9]+)?)` doesn't.

Is there a way to use parentheses in the capture groups to nest those groups?

Comment: why do you need a capture group on the 2nd to end character

Comment: @rioV8 The pattern is for variable names, which can not have numbers in the first character, but can have them in the following characters which are optional

Comment: yes I know but why make it a capture group: **2nd to end character**